# How to make iPhone app searchable when search from an iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I created an iPhone app and published to the iTunes. Now my client complainig when he search it from the iPad it doesn't display under iPad apps. He asked me to make it search under iPad also. Then how I can do this plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: Is the app optimized for the iPad?

Comment: no it not optimized.. he said it is ok but make it searchable from the iPad also

Comment: @Ares what can I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it if you tap the iPhone tab on your iPad.  If you want it to show up under iPad apps, it has to be an iPad app (or a Universal app, meaning it is designed for both iPhone and iPad).  If you are looking to optimize your app for iPad and make it a Universal app, here are some resources to get you started:

[Apple's Advanced App Tricks Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

[Creating a Universal iOS App Tutorial](http://blog.corywiles.com/creating-a-universal-ios-app-tutorial)

[Creating a Universal iOS Application](http://www.slideshare.net/cliffmcc/creating-a-universal-ios-application)

If you go to Xcode and start a new project, and click "Universal", Apple will have most of the work done for you.  You will also find that it is a lot more straightforward than it sounds; basically you use the same code with different nib files.  If you need more advanced control, you can always detect which device you are running on to do stuff programatically.

Comment: One weird thing I have noticed is that while my iPhone apps show up under the iPhone tab on an iPad search on most iPads, it does not seem to work on the test iPads at the Apple Store.  They might have some sort of weird filter on those iPads or their wifi for some sort of marketing reason.

Comment: What he asked was,, I have to make it display under both iPhone and iPad tabs. Can't I just set the project target device family into iPad/iPhone (to my existing app)

Comment: You can try.  However, I would highly recommend fully porting to iPad.  In most cases it is as simple as making another Nib or storyboard file.